# How can I allow multiple accounts to be registered using cookies? Source Provided

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Currently once you are on the page it will let one person register one account.

Yes I know this is not how it should be done. I am just messing around with cookies. So is there any way to make it so that there can be multiple accounts instead of just one.

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function registerCookie() {
    var user = prompt("Please enter your desired username:","");
    var pass = prompt("Please enter your desired password:","");
    if (user != "" && user != null && pass != "" && pass != null) {
        setCookie("username", user, 30);
        setCookie("password", pass, 30);
    }
}

function loginCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    var pass=getCookie("password");
    var check=prompt("Username");
    var check2=prompt("password");
    if (check == user && check2 == pass) {
        alert("Welcome back, " + user);
    } else {
        alert("False information");
    }
}

function start() {
    var response = prompt("Would you like to register?");
    if (response == "yes" || response == "Yes") {
        registerCookie();
    } else if (response == "no" || response == "No") {
        loginCookie();
    } else {
        alert("We did not understand your input");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can use some tricks here: use username as the name of cookie

```
function registerCookie() {
    var user = prompt("Please enter your desired username:","");
    var pass = prompt("Please enter your desired password:","");
    if (user != "" && user != null && pass != "" && pass != null) {
        setCookie("username_"+user, user, 30);
        setCookie("password_"+user, pass, 30);
    }
}

function loginCookie() {
    var checkUser=prompt("Username");
    var checkPass=prompt("password");
    var user=getCookie("username_"+checkUser);
    //alert(user)
    var pass=getCookie("password_"+checkUser);
    //alert(pass)
    if (checkUser == user && checkPass == pass) {
        alert("Welcome back, " + user);
    } else {
        alert("False information");
    }
}
```